# Javascript Variable Name as Json Object Name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

First of all the question title doesn't make sense. Im not sure how can I ask the question in a better way.

Im facing an issue in an Angular 8.1 project. There is a josn file Im importing that in the settings Class (its a service).
When the environment.ts file have a variable as app_company. the same name a json file also available. So if the client app_company matches the json file. all the config should be loaded from  that file. This is what I need to achieve 
What I tried so far is .

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';
import * as client1 from './client1.json';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SettingsService {

  newInstance:object;

  constructor() { }

  config(key : string){

    //  const newInstance = Object.create(window[environment.app_company].prototype);
    //  newInstance.constructor.apply(newInstance);
    //  return newInstance.key;
    //  const newInstance: any = new (<any>window)[environment.app_company];
    // console.log(Object.create(window[environment.app_company]));

     return environment.app_company.key;
  }
}
```

my json file will look like below

```
{
    "opNumberLabel" : "OP No"
}
```

So in the return section if I call `client1.opNumberLabel`

It works like my expectation , but I try to make that dynamic like `environment.app_company.key` it not working .

As you can see my tried are commented those are not worked so far :(.

Any hint will highly appreciated .
Thanks in advance,

Comment: It seems that you wan't to use a string variable to access an object's property, you can do this: `client1[environment.app_company.key]` [more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Comment: No , the issue is client1 is also dynamic like env app_company value is client1 ,client2 etc

Comment: You can store all the clients in an object: `const clients = {client1, client2, client3}` and use bracket notation to access the appropriate one: `clients[env.app_company]`

Comment: @Titus I tried that way, seems key is not accessible upto client1 is getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved.

```
export class SettingsService {

  clients = { client1 , client2  };
  app_company :string;
  default_client = 'client1';

  constructor() { }

  config(label : string){

      this.app_company = environment.app_company;
      if(this.clients[this.app_company].default.hasOwnProperty(label)){
        return this.clients[this.app_company].default[label];
      }else{
        return this.clients[this.default_client].default[label];
      }


  }
}
```

Thanks to @Titus for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to achieve something like that?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as settings from "./environment.json";

interface Settings {
  [key: string]: string
}

type Environment = {
  [key: string]: Partial<Settings>
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SettingsService {

  private environment: Environment = {
    app_company: { }
  };

  constructor() {
    this.environment.app_company = settings;
    console.log(this.config("opNumberLabel")); // OP No
  }

  config(key : string){
     return this.environment.app_company[key];
  }
}
```

```
{
  "opNumberLabel" : "OP No",
  "settings1": "testSettings1",
  "settings2": "testSettings2"
}
```

If you would like to have `app_company` as a dynamic value too, then I would suggest to extend the example:

- by creating an `init` function which could also accept the name of
  the `client`.
- by passing an object to the `SettingsService`
  constructor, with `InjectionToken`, so you can define what is the
  current client you are trying to configure.

You might also want to have different environment setup for different clients, so I would suggest to create separate environment json files for each client.
You could create an object which would hold every `<client>.environment.json` with `<client>` key.

After that you have an object, like that:

```
const clientEnvironments: Environment = {
    client1: { ... },
    client2: { ... }
};
```

So by having the name of your current client, you can easily select which environment you want to use.